# How should I override equals and hashcode method to avoid adding equal objects o HashSet?

Tags: java

I have studied similar examples and override these methods like this, but still get added to the `HashSet<NamedObject>` objects with the equal names BUT different id.

```
public class NamedObject {
    String name;
    BigInteger id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        NamedObject that = (NamedObject) o;
        return this.name.equals(that.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct `equals` method you need ?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why would this work?

Comment: I suppose two objects are the equal, if they have the equal names. Or are you talking about checking the instance of argument?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding equal objects, i check class of argument and names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have studied similar examples and override these methods like this, but still get added to the `HashSet<NamedObject>` objects with the equal names BUT different id.

Yes, because you're only using the `id` in the hash code, and only using the `name` in the equality check. `HashSet<>` will only call `equals()` when it finds an existing object with the same hash code as the one you're trying to add... if your IDs are different, it's highly unlikely that the hash codes will be different, so it's never calling `equals` with the object that has the same name.

Your `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods *must* be consistent with each other. You need to decide whether equality is based on name, ID, or both - and then use that in both `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

From the [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) documentation:

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Your methods break the middle of these requirements at the moment.

Comment: This is my mistake, I don't correctly ask a question. I want to have a HashSet<NamedObject> with objects,which have unique names. Therefore, in checking for equivalence I check only the names. But I still get added to my set object with equal names.

Comment: @will_hunting: But your code doesn't do that. It uses `id` for the hash code instead of `name`. To fix it, all you need to do is change `hashCode()` to return `name.hashCode()`.